# Hexadecimal Globally Unique Identifier (GUID) Algorithm in Node/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, guid

Is it possible to create a GUID using 16 characters of hex? The reason I ask is Cloudflare is using 16 characters to identify each request to their system (they call them "Ray IDs"). They look much nicer compared to other GUID formats (I know this is silly preference).

The key space would contain these characters:

```
0-9
a-f
---
16 total possible characters

Example: adttlo9dOd8haoww
```

Also, any hint to a basic algorithm of generating these things would be awesome.

Lastly, I'm open to leaving the "hex" format and using:

```
0-9
a-z
A-Z
---
62 total possible characters

Example: dhmpLTuPFWEwM8UL
```

Comment: Are you trying to generate these GUIDs on a single server such that they are unique to that server?  Or are you trying to generate these in multiple places such they are globally unique (a much, much harder task).

Comment: Globally unique would be nice, not sure if it is possible with just 16 characters

Comment: If you need globally unique and coined across many different systems in 16 characters, I can't help you.  If you just need it globally unique when only coined on one server or on a fixed number of servers all in contact with one another, I could help you.  That doesn't even take 16 characters.

Comment: There are a lot of modules available on NPM, just have a look: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=guid Also, read http://blog.tompawlak.org/generate-unique-identifier-nodejs-javascript and have a look at http://t-pwk.github.io/flake-idgen/

Answer (score 0):

1. When you need to create your own unique id's use date time now. If your application is distributed use datetime.now + node identifier this is the most simple solution:

```js
function d2h(d) {
    return d.toString(16);
}
function h2d (h) {
    return parseInt(h, 16);
}
function stringToHex (tmp) {
    var str = '',
        i = 0,
        tmp_len = tmp.length,
        c;
 
    for (; i < tmp_len; i += 1) {
        c = tmp.charCodeAt(i);
        str += d2h(c) + ' ';
    }
    return str;
}
function hexToString (tmp) {
    var arr = tmp.split(' '),
        str = '',
        i = 0,
        arr_len = arr.length,
        c;
 
    for (; i < arr_len; i += 1) {
        c = String.fromCharCode( h2d( arr[i] ) );
        str += c;
    }
 
    return str;
}
//if you can get utc time is even bether
// Tue, 30 Jun 2015 23:01:04 GMT
var time = Date();
var server_point = "S1";
//you can encript this genrated id with blow fish or something, remember encripting existen bytes the length of the result wil grow
//remove spaces
var reg = new RegExp("[ ]+","g");
time = time.replace(reg, "");
var hexaResult = stringToHex(time + server_point);
alert(hexaResult.replace(reg, ""));
```

2. Or you can use crypto random generator:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RandomSource/getRandomValues

Answer (score 0):

Guids are typically 32 hex characters with dashes at different intervals.

```
var crypto = require("crypto");

function create_guid() {
    var hexstring = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("hex"); // 16 bytes generates a 32 character hex string
    var guidstring = hexstring.substring(0,8) + "-" + hexstring.substring(8,12) + "-" + hexstring.substring(12,16) + "-" + hexstring.substring(16,20) + "-" + hexstring.substring(20);
    return guidstring;
}
```

You can simply modify the above function to return `hexstring` instead of `guidstring` if you don't want the dashes.  And if want just 16 characters instead of 32:

```
function create_guid_simple() {
    var hexstring = crypto.randomBytes(8).toString("hex"); // 8 bytes is a 16 character string
    return hexstring;
}
```